# How to stop a systemd linux serviceB.service after a serviceA.service has failed

Tags: linux, service, linux-kernel, system, systemd

I am running 2 systemd services - serviceA.service and serviceB.service. In my scenario, serviceA.service fails at startup showing -

```
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/serviceA.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2023-07-24 15:03:53 UTC; 10min ago ...
```

ServiceB needs to stop if serviceA failed. Note: ServiceB is of Type forking and I am not supposed to change that.

I added "After=serviceA.service and Requires=serviceA.service" in my serviceB.service file but it does not seem to work. I even tried the "BindTo=" keyword but it didn't work too. My serviceA.service also has an "OnFailure=" keyword but that doesn't help too. My theory is that serviceB's keywords only check if serviceA is running but don't check if it has failed or passed. Can someone please explain what would be the best way to solve this problem? (I am open to any kind of solution involving a custom script or new keywords)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as the systemd tag states: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com. Please delete this.

Answer (score -2):

Update: I found the solution to this by changing the type of service to "one shot", adding the "RemainAdterExit=true" keyword to serviceA, and adding the "BindsTo=" keyword in serviceB (serviceB has the same type=forking)